# How to insert data from XML in MySql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Actually i'm trying to create a program in VB.NET that get xml files from a folder and set it's data to MySQL.

Each XML file has unique ID for which is created a database and all tables.
In the folder i can have files like "DC_001" "DF_001" "DC_002" and that's mean that the data from the XML file DC_001 have to be placed in database 001 in table DC.

Actually i've made the method which create the database for each unique ID and it's tables but as i'm not very in to VB.NET i need some suggestion on how to put the data inside the XML to each database.

Here is my method where i create the database and tables.

```
    Dim PIVA As New ArrayList
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root; password=block; database=mysql"

    For Each fileName As String In Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("C:\Users\imytyuk\Desktop\test")
        Dim file As String = Trim(EstrCampo("_", fileName, 1, 2))
        If Not PIVA.Contains(file) Then
            PIVA.Add(file)
        End If
    Next

    For Each iva In PIVA
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE `" & iva & "`", conn)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            conn.Close()
            CreaTB(iva)
        Catch
        End Try
    Next
```

While here is like a XML file can be structured

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to use the following method to insert the data from XML but i get ""Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"}" as Exception.

Here is the code:

```
Sub AddXML()
        For Each fileName As String In Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries("C:\Users\imytyuk\Desktop\test")
            databaseFilePut(fileName, "datacollect", Trim(EstrCampo("_", fileName, 1, 2)))
            File.Delete(fileName)
        Next

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub databaseFilePut(ByVal varFilePath As String, ByVal table As String, ByVal db As String)
        Dim file() As Byte
        Dim stream = New FileStream(varFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim reader = New BinaryReader(stream)
        file = reader.ReadBytes(CType(stream.Length, Integer))
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;user id=root; password=block; database=" & db
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & table & " Values(@File)", conn)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", MySqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: For new code, please don't use ArrayList. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks

Comment: I guess we need to see the CreateTB method since the number of columns in the table do not match the number of parameters you are passing in.

Comment: BinaryReader? Isn't an xml file essentially a text file?

Comment: Do you really want to dump that Binary rendition of the file contents all in one column and let someone else figure out how to extract it?